# one of the output is showing (null) result on a simple struct program (no Array of Struct)

Tags: c, struct

I've created a simple program for displaying college student data and counting the accumulation of score into a grade (A,B,C,D,E) and using struct (Im prohibited to create with Array of Struct), so the problem is one of the output which is "Grade" is giving (null) result when printed with %s and completely blank result when printed with %c. The type of the "Grade" data is char by the way. Here is the complete code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct student
{
char nim[11];
char name[100];
char subjectCode[5];
int sks;
char grade;
}studentScore[100];

bool cekKarakter(char input[])
{
for(int x = 0; x < strlen(input); x++)
{
    if(isdigit(input[x]))
    return false;
}
return true;
}

bool cekNumeric(char input[])
{
for(int x = 0; x < strlen(input); x++)
{
    if(input[x] >= 48 && input[x] <= 57)
    return false;
}
return true;
}

int main()
{
int n;
printf("Input number of Student Data: ");
scanf("%d", &n); 
fflush(stdin);
printf("\n\n");
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    do
    {
        printf("NIM [Hanya numerik][10 Digit]: ");
        gets(studentScore[i].nim);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while(strlen(studentScore[i].nim) != 10 || 
 cekNumeric(studentScore[i].nim));

    printf("\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Name [Hanya karakter]: ");
        gets(studentScore[i].name); 
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while(strlen(studentScore[i].name) < 5 || strlen(studentScore[i].name) > 
 30 || cekKarakter(studentScore[i].name) == false);

    printf("\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Subject Code [Must 5 length]: ");
        gets(studentScore[i].subjectCode); 
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while(strlen(studentScore[i].subjectCode) != 5);

    printf("\n");

    do
    {
        printf("SKS [Min 2|Max 8]: ");
        scanf("%d", &studentScore[i].sks); 
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while(studentScore[i].sks < 2 || studentScore[i].sks > 8);

    printf("\n");

    int score[5];
    int WeightGrade = 0; 

    printf("Input 5 College Subject Score:\n\n");
    for(int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Input Score[%d][Must be between 0 and 100]: ", z + 1);
            scanf("%d", &score[z]);
        }
        while(score[z] < 0 || score[z] > 100);

        WeightGrade += score[z];
    }

    if(WeightGrade / 25 == 4)
    {
        studentScore[i].grade = 'A';
    }
    else if(WeightGrade / 25 >= 3 && WeightGrade / 25 < 4)
    {
        studentScore[i].grade = 'B';
    }
    else if(WeightGrade / 25 >= 2 && WeightGrade / 25 < 3)
    {
        studentScore[i].grade = 'C';
    }
    else if(WeightGrade / 25 >= 1 && WeightGrade / 25 < 2)
    {
        studentScore[i].grade = 'D';
    }
    else if(WeightGrade / 25 == 0)
    {
        studentScore[i].grade = 'E';
    }
}

printf("\nStudent Data\n");

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    printf("NIM: %s\nName: %s\nSubject Code: %s\nSKS: %d\nGrade: %s\n",
        studentScore[i].nim, 
        studentScore[i].name, 
        studentScore[i].subjectCode, 
        studentScore[i].sks, 
        studentScore[i].grade); 
}
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

This is the image of the program when it's running
[(null) output result using %s as printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovmdh.png)

Comment: Try adding an else clause that sets the grade to '?' when testing WeightGrade in the if-else-if block, then you see the fault

Comment: thank you for the debugging method, i will keep this in mind everytime i have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, WeightGrade is actually the sum of all grades, so for your example - WeightGrade=370.

370/25 doesn't fall within any of the options, so studentScore[i].grade doesn't get any value. To prevents this cases, always input an else clause that shows an error

Since you have 5 values, you should divide by 5*25=125, as in WeightGrade/125

Also for printf, you shouldn't use %s on char value, you should use %c

Comment: I have resolved this issue instantly after changing the equation from divided by 25 to 125 according to the 5 score accumulation, and also changing the printed result using %c (because of single char) instead of %s. Thank you for correcting this.

Comment: If this solves your issue, please mark it as answered